# SQL retrieve info from 2 different ID in a single query

Tags: sql

Let's say I have a table that represents soccer matches (X_train in this case) with an away_team_id and a home_team_id, those id points to another table 'team_attributes'.

What I managed to do with a query is to select the attributes of only one of the team but I'm interested in getting both team's attributes.

This is the query I'm using now :

```
SELECT 
    X_Train.* , Team_Attributes.*, MAX(Team_Attributes.date)
FROM 
    X_Train
LEFT JOIN 
    Team_Attributes ON X_Train.home_team_api_id = Team_Attributes.team_api_id 
                    AND Team_Attributes.date <= X_Train.date
GROUP BY 
    X_Train.id
ORDER BY 
    X_Train.date
```

This works fine but I need to get the same join on the X_train.away_team_api_id, is there an easy way to do this ? I tried using UNION but maybe I didn't look far enough in that direction.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a second join.  For that -- and to simplify the query -- use table aliases:

```
SELECT t.*, hta.*, ata.*

FROM X_Train t LEFT JOIN
     Team_Attributes hta
     ON t.home_team_api_id = hta.team_api_id  AND
        hta.date <= t.date LEFT JOIN
     Team_Attributes ata
     ON t.away_team_api_id = ata.team_api_id  AND
        ata.date <= t.date
ORDER BY t.date DESC;
```

I don't understand what the `GROUP BY` is doing, so I removed it.  Your question appears to be about `JOIN` logic anyway.

Comment: Group by is assuring there a no duplicate rows ;)